# “Such a, such the, such” rules

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, such

**1- Mr Andrew is ......man that you can trust him**.

a) such a.   b) such an.   C) such the.

**2- Mr Andrew is......man that you can trust.**

a)such an    b)such the    c) such

I am a bit confused, can someone provide an explanation for each one? Thanks in advance

Comment: None of the options result in a sentence that's idiomatic or grammatical.

Comment: Yeah I thought so but I got them from a book, so can’t “such” precede the noun “without an adj like the examples”? 
Or can we treat “man that you can trust” as an adjective? 
Idk I’m  just trying to figure it out it’s hard for a book to have 2 wrong examples

Comment: Oh thanks .. one more question: shouldn’t “him” in the first sentence be eliminated?

Comment: The sentence *Mr. Andrew is such a man*, is fine. (Although it would be odd unless it followed a question or previous sentence.) There's nothing wrong with such itself, but none of the sentences are correctly formed with any of the choices. Such, in this sense, is being used as a pronoun.

Comment: *You can trust him* is fine. So would be (although it's unusual) *such a man is Mr. Andrews that you can trust him.* But in that second case here, it's actually being used as an adjective rather than a pronoun. In fact, the more I read that version, the more I think the first sentence with just *such* might actually be okay. It's just not how anybody would normally write or parse it.